# Nancy testing GetModel<T> throws KeyNotFoundException

Tags: nancy

I'm trying to test that the model returned from my Nancy application is as expected. I have followed the docs [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application#digging-deeper-with-test-extensions) but whenever I call the `GetModel<T>` extension method it throws a `KeyNotFoundException`.

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

I know what the error means but I'm failing to see why it's being thrown.

Here's my module

```
public class SanityModule : NancyModule
{
    public SanityModule()
    {
        Get["sanity-check"] = _ => Negotiate.WithModel(new SanityViewModel { Id = 1 })
                                            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

my view model

```
public class SanityViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and here's my test

```
[TestFixture]
public class SanityModuleTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Sanity_Check()
    {
        // Arrange
        var browser = new Browser(with =>
        {
            with.Module<SanityModule>();
            with.ViewFactory<TestingViewFactory>();
        });

        // Act
        var result = browser.Get("/sanity-check", with =>
        {
            with.HttpRequest();
            with.Header("accept", "application/json");
        });
        var model = result.GetModel<SanityViewModel>();

        // Asset
        model.Id.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(1);
    }
}
```

Debugging this test shows that the module is hit and completes just fine. Running the application shows that the response is as expected.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I believe `GetModel<T>` is meant to get the model behind a rendered html-view. You can just deserialise json to the SanityModel to check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the lovely guys, [albertjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117242/albertjan) and [the.fringe.ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408866/jo%C3%A3o-bragan%C3%A7a), in the [Nancy Jabbr room](https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/nancyfx) we've got an explanation as to what's going on here.

**TL;DR** It makes sense for this to not work but the error message should be more descriptive. There is a workaround below.

The issue here is that I am requesting the response as `application/json` whilst using `TestingViewFactory`.

Let's take a look at the implementation of `GetModel<T>();`

```
public static TType GetModel<TType>(this BrowserResponse response)
{
    return (TType)response.Context.Items[TestingViewContextKeys.VIEWMODEL];
}
```

This is simply grabbing the view model from the `NancyContext` and casting it to your type. **This is where the error is thrown, as there is no view model in `NancyContext`**. This is because the view model is added to NancyContext in the `RenderView` method of `TestingViewFactory`.

```
public Response RenderView(string viewName, dynamic model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)
{
    // Intercept and store interesting stuff
    viewLocationContext.Context.Items[TestingViewContextKeys.VIEWMODEL] = model;
    viewLocationContext.Context.Items[TestingViewContextKeys.VIEWNAME] = viewName;
    viewLocationContext.Context.Items[TestingViewContextKeys.MODULENAME] = viewLocationContext.ModuleName;
    viewLocationContext.Context.Items[TestingViewContextKeys.MODULEPATH] = viewLocationContext.ModulePath;

    return this.decoratedViewFactory.RenderView(viewName, model, viewLocationContext);
}
```

My test is requesting json so RenderView will not be called. This means you can only use `GetModel<T>` if you use a html request.

**Workaround**

My application is an api so I do not have any views so changing the line

```
with.Header("accept", "application/json");
```

to

```
with.Header("accept", "text/html");
```

will throw a `ViewNotFoundException`. To avoid this I need to implement my own `IViewFactory`. (this comes from [the.fringe.ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408866/jo%C3%A3o-bragan%C3%A7a))

```
public class TestViewFactory : IViewFactory
{
    #region IViewFactory Members

    public Nancy.Response RenderView(string viewName, dynamic model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)
    {
        viewLocationContext.Context.Items[Fixtures.SystemUnderTest.ViewModelKey] = model;
        return new HtmlResponse();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then it is simply a case of updating

```
with.ViewFactory<TestingViewFactory>();
```

to

```
with.ViewFactory<TestViewFactory>();
```

Now `GetModel<T>` should work without needing a view.

Comment: Ouch my head... I ended up just Deserializing the response myself instead of trying to get `GetModel<>` to work.

Comment: Good explanation -- at least I know that I am not crazy.  Unfortunately, this did not work for me.  I am using MSTest so `Fixtures.SystemUnderTest.ViewModelKey` wasn't defined for me.